# Getting Unauthorized error in spring rest api , even /authenticate route is protected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I am trying access /authenticate route it show this error in postman

{
"timestamp": "2022-01-20T07:50:45.532+0000",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Access Denied",
"path": "/authenticate/"
}

and /authenticate route authenticates the user and return jwt token

**CODE**

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping({ "/hello" })
    public String firstPage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }


        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }

}
```

Spring Security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                        anyRequest().authenticated().
                        and().
                        exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

}
```

Comment: Give permit all to all the requests and check if it's happening again? Let me know the results

Comment: if I permit all request then /authenticate and /hello works fine, but I need protect /hello

Comment: The error shows the denied path was '/authenticate/'. Was the test done with '/authenticate' or '/authenticate/' with a slash at the end also?

Comment: Try giving '/authenticate/**' in antMatchers